# is there a way to create and init a dir variable in one line using pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I try to stick to pathlib to create and manipulate path but generating folders is always a pain. If I want to init a "toto" folder in a "tutu" folder and store the path in a variable I'm forced to do the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path 

tutu = Path("tutu")
toto = tutu / "toto"
toto.mkdir()
```

Is there a way to generate `toto` variable AND init the folder in one line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
>>> (toto := tutu / "toto").mkdir()
>>> toto
PosixPath('tutu/toto')
```

But more Pythonic  would be just to define a utility function.

Comment: why isn't it pythonic ? it's a cool way to use a python>=3.8 feature isn't it ?

Comment: Personally I'd rather see this on multiple lines. More readable that way.

Comment: On my side, I would prefer mkdir to have a return statement in the first place